# Qual é a finalidade do input do tipo "Image"?

Tags: html, formulário, input, image

Só agora fui perceber esses dias que existe um `input` com o atributo `type` igual a `"image"`.

Vi isso sendo usado em algum site (bem antigo por sinal) para fazer submissão de um formulário.

Tenho as seguintes dúvidas:

- Qual é a finalidade desse `input[type=image]`?
- Ele serve apenas para fazer submissão de formulário?
- Esse atributo deve ser evitado, ou ainda pode ser utilizado tranquilamente (estamos em 2017 só pra constar a data)?

Referência: [MDN - Input Type Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Estilização

O motivo mais óbvio é pra fazer um botão de submissão mais "bonitinho" usando uma imagem no lugar do botão padrão. Se tornou desnecessário desde o HTML5 já que todos objetos do documento podem ser estilizados de outras formas.

E ele nem funciona igual ao que se espera de um botão em todas situações (pode não enviar o valor do botão e sim as coordenadas de onde foi clicado que é pouco relevante em quase todos casos e tira uma possível informação que importa), então o evite. Prefira o [`button`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#button-state-(type=button)) que faz o que deve fazer.

Isso foi criado meio que por gambiarra pra resolver um problema sem pensar no todo.

## Imagem mapeada

Existe um outro motivo um pouco melhor que é mapear imagem. O formulário com essa *tag* enviará as coordenadas do *click* dado na imagem e isso poderá ajudar tomar decisão. Há casos que a posição de onde deu o *click* determine a ação.

É possível [mapear imagens só na página](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map). Quando usa isso no formulário indica que quer que o dado a ser enviado ao formulário é o *click*. [Exemplo](https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/forms/image-type-example/xy-coordinates-example.html). [Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image#Using_image_inputs) ("Using the x and y data points"). [Ferramenta para ajudar mapeamento](https://www.image-map.net/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).